# Calling of afterSave method in application.php file slowing down complete platform and showing memory_limit exceed error

Tags: events, cakephp, orm, cakephp-4.x

I am calling afterSave method in application.php to perform action on all models saving event. Issue is whenever I using SAVE method inside afterSave method application showing fatal error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

Point is same method working fine in specific model, without any memory exhausted error, I think there is something that need to be fixed over database connection. Below is the code which one I am trying.

```
//Application.php file

namespace App;
...
...
\Cake\Event\EventManager::instance()->on(
    'Model.afterSave',
    function (
        \Cake\Event\EventInterface $event,
        \Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity,
        \ArrayObject $options
    ) {
    $auth_data = isset($_SESSION['Auth'])?$_SESSION['Auth']:[];
    $ActionLogs = TableRegistry::get('ActionLogs');
    $ActionLogsEntity = $ActionLogs->newEmptyEntity();
    $ActionLogsEntity->change_log = $change_log;
    $ActionLogsEntity->action_taken_by = $auth_data->username;
    $ActionLogs->save($ActionLogsEntity); //This statement working fine in specific modelTable

class Application extends BaseApplication
implements AuthenticationServiceProviderInterface
   {
    ...
    ...
   }
```

Comment: The code was supposed to go into the `bootstrap()` method of the `Application` class!

Comment: I added inside ```bootstrap()``` as well, in both situations giving same error,

Comment: Well, the correct place is the bootstrap method, so you should go from there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the fact that the code should go into the `Application` class' `bootstrap()` method as mentioned in the comments, when you save inside of an `afterSave` event that listens to all models, then you naturally create a recursion, as saving the log will trigger an `afterSave` event too.

You have to put a safeguard in place that prevents the logging logic from running when the `afterSave` event belongs to the logging model, for example:

```php
if ($event->getSubject() instanceof \App\Model\Table\ActionLogsTable) {
    return;
}

// ...
```